# Making a class based view with allows redirecting after POST in django rest framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to make a class based view whereby after after HTTP status `201` it redirects to another url which is something like `/pending_for_approval` ? I have a Leave model for employees, if an employee applies for a leave and successfully fills out the form he be redirected to another url stating the application has completed and is pending for approval ,the employee can also view the result of the view he he/she filled out. How do I implement this?

Here is my view so far:

```
class LeaveApplyAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    """
        {   "applicant":1,
            "approver":1,
            "leave_type":1,
            "leave_subject":"Sick Off",
            "leave_reason":"Sick",
            "start_date":"YY-MM-DD",
            "return_date":"YY-MM-DD"
        }
    """
    # 'slug'-means pecific keyword
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    # permission_classes = (permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions,)
    serializer_class = ApplyLeaveSerializer

    def total_days(self, start_date, return_date):
        oneday = timedelta(days=1)
        # convert str to datetime
        start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        return_date = datetime.strptime(return_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        total_days = 0
        while (start_date <= return_date):
            if not start_date.isoweekday() in (6, 7):
                total_days += 1
            start_date += oneday
        return total_days

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        leaves = Leave.objects.all()
        serializer = ApplyLeaveSerializer(leaves, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)

        start_date = request.data.get('start_date')
        return_date = request.data.get('return_date')
        total_days = self.total_days(start_date, return_date)

        applicant = Employee.objects.get(id=request.data.pop('applicant'))

        leave_type = LeaveType.objects.get(id=request.data.pop('leave_type'))
        leave_subject = request.data.get('leave_subject')
        leave_reason = request.data.get('leave_reason')
        slug = request.data.get('slug')
        apply_on = request.data.get('apply_on')

        leave = Leave.objects.create(**request.data)
        leave.total_days = total_days
        leave.slug = slug
        leave.apply_on = apply_on
        leave.applicant = applicant
        leave.leave_type = leave_type
        leave.leave_subject = leave_subject
        leave.leave_reason = leave_reason
        leave.save()

        serializer = ApplyLeaveSerializer(leave)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 1):

One common pattern in AJAX POST submissions is to use a respond with a redirect URL in the JSON Response, and allow the FE framework to perform redirection.

Assuming you're using AJAX, why not pass a redirect_url to the FE and perform the redirect on the FE?

```
serializer = ApplyLeaveSerializer(leave)
resp = serializer.data
resp['redirect_url'] = 'xyz'
return Response(resp, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

And in your FE you can do:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
})
.done(function(data) {
    redirect_url = data.redirect_url;
    alert('Redirecting!');
    window.location = redirect_url;
}
```